# execute command via ssh with password

Tags: linux

I want to execute two command on two servers via ssh from my local machine

```
ssh user@"$APP_HOST" "sh /home/agents/startAgent.sh --auto-shutdown > agent.log 2>&1 </dev/null & "
ssh user@"$DB_HOST" "sh /home/agents/startAgent.sh --auto-shutdown > agent.log 2>&1 </dev/null & "
```

with `APP_HOST` it works fine and starts `.sh.` script on remote just ok.

But my `DB_HOST` asks for password when I try to run the same command. For now I don't have configured access without password (no rights to do).

But how to provide password inside the command itself without input?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a different behaviour for the same ssh command, it's probably an SSH miscounfiguration.

Check you SSH config file, it there is no difference, check you ssh keys.

What does a simple `ssh user@"$DB_HOST"` do?

Comment: it is part of the script, that accepts input parameter and pass it to expression

Comment: You can't try `ssh user@"$DB_HOST"` ? Just to see if you can connect and compare with APP_HOST.
My point is to isolate the possible issue.

Comment: it works via `ssh` but it asks password

Comment: If I understand:
`ssh user@"$APP_HOST"` -> No password required. `ssh user@"$DB_HOST"` -> Password prompt.
It really seems that the ssh configuration for these two hosts is different.
1. Check the ssh config file ~/.ssh/config and compare them
2. Check the key pair

Comment: Yeah, it is possible. I will contact devops team tomorrow. I just thought I could something ad hoc right now without additional installation.

Answer (score 0):

You have to install private key of user launch remotely the command to the user in the remote server. If you have the password of remote user you have the right to install your private key, just run

```
ssh-copy-if user@"$DB_HOST"
```

You will prompt for the user password and from that moment on you can login to remote server without password prompt. 
No configuration have to be change openssh server is configured to accept key authentication for default.

Answer (score 0):

You can install and use one of various ssh-askpass packages (ssh-askpass, ssh-askpass-gnome, ksshaskpass (KDE), ssh-askpass-fullscreen (Gnome2),...) and force a password-prompt (in your X-session) to open each time a password is requested.

A good explanation is the first answer in this post: [Tell SSH to use a graphical prompt for key passphrase](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/83991/332764)

Comment: the problem is that it is a corporate server, I cannot simply install tools there. Hell, I am not even sure if I can install JAVA there. so basically there is no way to do that out-of-the-box?

Comment: I understand. And I guess "sshpass" is also not installed which would make `sshpass -ppassword ssh user@host` possible? (Yes, this program is not very secure, but might be a workaround)

Comment: no, not installed either

Answer (score 0):

Create new authentication key pairs for SSH, do not enter value in passphrase (On terminal)

1. `ssh-keygen -t rsa`
2. `ssh-copy-id -i /home/local_user/.ssh/id_rsa user@$DB_HOST`
3. `ssh-keygen -f "/home/local_user/.ssh/known_hosts" -R "$DB_HOST"`

Execute (Your shell script)

`ssh -t user@$APP_HOST 'sh /home/agents/startAgent.sh --auto-shutdown > agent.log 2>&1 </dev/null & '`

`ssh -t  user@$DB_HOST 'sh /home/agents/startAgent.sh --auto-shutdown > agent.log 2>&1 </dev/null & '`